# Receive files and save them on socket Python

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

My server is sending serial of files with name like file_1, file_2, and so on. 
The sending socket works well and I've checked those files all correct.

**Server** - sending files

```
f = open(new_filename, 'rb')
            start_ts = ts
            seconds += 1
            try:
                print('Sending %s' % new_filename)
                conn.sendall(f.read(99999999))
                f.flush()
                f.close()
            except socket.error:
                if errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
                    print(os.strerror(socket.error.errno))
                else:
                    raise
                print('Send failed')
                sys.exit()
```

Here on the client side, I want to receive those files and save them as the way it was on the server (save_1, save_2, ...) on my computer.

**Client**- receive files and try to save them

```
try:
        client.send(b'Receiving Data...\n')
        while True:
            save_filename = 'savefolder/save_%i.pcap' % file_index
            f = open(save_filename, 'wb')
            data = client.recv(99999999)
            f.write(data)
            reply = b'Message Received.\n'
            if not data:
                break
            client.sendall(reply)
            f.close()
            file_index += 1
    except socket.timeout:
        print('Done receiving.', end=' ')
        client.close()
        print('Client socket is closed')
```

1. But the saved files look weird. When the server sends one 3,755 KB file, the client writes two files with 192KB and 3,563KB. Worse, the bigger one crashes. Is there a fix for this? I don't know why it happens here with my code.
2. Is it the only way to input 99999999 value to get the entire file without cutting?
3. Why is my client not sending message to the server even though I wrote some code in there?

Answer (score 0):

TCP is not a message based protocol but a byte stream protocol. There is no fixed relation between how much was `send` or `sendall` and how much gets read with `recv`.

In order to send multiple messages (files) over the same connection you have to define some application protocol which clearly defines where messages start and end. And alternative would be to use a new TCP connection for each file and read until `recv` returns `''`, i.e. indicates that the other site has closed the connection.